# Algebraic step including finite sum and binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, algebras

[image]

Hello,
I've stumbled into the following algebraic step in my combinatorics text book. 
Beside calculating it directly, I can't find a proper justification for it.

Someone's got an idea?

Comment: i got $2\cdot 0.8=1.6$ for your sum

Comment: What's wrong with computing it directly?

Comment: You recognize that the term contains an expected value calculation of the expected number of successes in 10 Bernoulli trials with probability of success p = 0.2 which is known to be equal to np = 10*0.2 in this case

Comment: I think BenB answer is very intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer below is good direct calculation but the point is you don’t need to work that hard

Answer (score 2):

This is
$$\frac45\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}k\frac{4^{10-k}}{5^{10}}$$
But
$$k\binom{10}k=k\frac{10!}{k!(10-k)!}=10\frac{9!}{(k-1)!(10-k)!}
=10\binom{9}{k-1}.$$
Your sum is
$$8\sum_{k=1}^{10}\binom{9}{k-1}\frac{4^{10-k}}{5^{10}}
=\frac85\sum_{j=0}^{9}\binom{9}{j}\frac{4^{9-j}}{5^{9}}=\frac85
\frac{(1+4)^9}{5^9}=\frac85$$
(using binomial theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The point is to recognize that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{10} \binom{10}{k} \cdot 0.2^k \cdot 0.8^{10-k} 
 \cdot k$ is the expected value calculation of the expected number of successes in 10 successive, independent Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p=0.2$.  The value of this sum is commonly known to equal $np$ where $n$ is the number of trials, which equals $10 \cdot 0.2 = 2$ in this case.

One way to remember the $np$ formula is to let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of successful trials and to let $X_i$ be an indicator R.V. for the success of trial $i$.  Then $$X = \sum_{i =1}^nX_i \implies E[X] = E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_I \right] = \sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n p = np$$

Answer (score 0):

$$=0.8\sum_{k=0}^{10} \binom {10}{k} (0.2)^k * (0.8)^{10-k}.k$$
$$=(0.8)*(0.2)\sum_{k=1}^{10} \binom {9}{k-1} * (0.2)^{k-1} *  (0.8)^{10-k}.k.\frac{10}{k}$$
$$=(0.8)*(0.2)*(10)\sum_{k=1}^{10} \binom {9}{k-1} (0.2)^{k-1} *  (0.8)^{10-k}$$
Also we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10} \binom {9}{k-1} (0.2)^{k-1} *  (0.8)^{10-k}=(0.8+0.2)^9=1^9=1$$

Hence

$$(0.8)*(0.2)*10\sum_{k=1}^{10} \binom {9}{k-1} (0.2)^{k-1} * (0.8)^{10-k}=(0.8)*(0.2)*(10)=1.6$$